# problem in installing libfreenect2 on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, make, udev, makefile

I'm trying to install libfreenect2.

I have cloned the repository.

I have made cmake successfully.

But when I `make` the file, I get the following error:

```
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/generate_resources_tool.dir/src/generate_resources.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:314:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdlib:72,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_string.h:2850,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/satellite/libfreenect2/examples/protonect/src/generate_resources.cpp:27:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:222:28: fatal error: sys/sysmacros.h: No such file or directory
 # include <sys/sysmacros.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/generate_resources_tool.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/generate_resources_tool.dir/src/generate_resources.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/generate_resources_tool.dir/src/generate_resources.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:200: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/generate_resources_tool.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/generate_resources_tool.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It is so annoying. I couldn't solve where the problem is.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing header file is part of more than one package. Check this first (you have 64-bit)

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-amd64
```

or for 32-bit (for later readers with 32-bit systems)

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
```

---

Have a look at the packages with this header file [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=trusty&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=sys%2Fsysmacros.h).

Comment: libc6-dev-amd64 or libc6-dev?

Comment: libc6dev-dev-amd64

Comment: Oh, I see `libc6-dev` is a dependency of `libc6-dev-amd64`